# How to merge two tables as mentioned int following post?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, python

I have two data sets:
1)
Date::

```
01/03/16 00:00:01
01/03/16 00:00:11
01/03/16 00:00:21
01/03/16 00:00:31
01/03/16 00:00:41
01/03/16 00:00:51
01/03/16 00:01:01
01/03/16 00:01:11
01/03/16 00:01:21 
.....
```

until 31/03/16 23:59:58 with each date row have a difference of 10 sec.

and

2)
Start Date::

```
29/02/16 21:58:03
01/03/16 07:07:18
01/03/16 07:07:37
01/03/16 07:07:38
01/03/16 07:07:47
01/03/16 07:10:06
01/03/16 07:10:36
01/03/16 08:46:09
01/03/16 08:46:29
01/03/16 08:48:39
01/03/16 08:51:17
01/03/16 08:51:47
01/03/16 09:00:14
01/03/16 09:01:53
01/03/16 09:33:50
01/03/16 09:34:40
01/03/16 09:47:25
01/03/16 10:14:55
01/03/16 10:15:05
01/03/16 10:15:15
01/03/16 10:15:35
01/03/16 10:19:43
01/03/16 10:17:03
01/03/16 10:19:53
01/03/16 10:21:02
01/03/16 10:21:42
01/03/16 11:03:25
01/03/16 12:49:24
01/03/16 12:49:27
01/03/16 12:51:07
01/03/16 12:52:07
01/03/16 12:52:37
01/03/16 13:59:30
01/03/16 13:59:40
01/03/16 14:00:59
01/03/16 14:01:00
01/03/16 14:01:09
01/03/16 14:01:39
01/03/16 14:08:16
01/03/16 14:10:06
01/03/16 14:40:54
01/03/16 14:41:47
01/03/16 14:42:17
01/03/16 14:42:47
01/03/16 15:26:00
01/03/16 15:26:59
01/03/16 15:27:29
01/03/16 15:28:29
01/03/16 18:32:40
01/03/16 18:34:29
01/03/16 18:34:49
01/03/16 18:39:17
01/03/16 18:39:27
01/03/16 18:57:11
01/03/16 18:58:20
01/03/16 19:57:56
01/03/16 19:58:06
01/03/16 19:59:16
01/03/16 19:59:36
01/03/16 20:01:24
01/03/16 20:40:20
01/03/16 20:41:09
01/03/16 20:41:59
01/03/16 20:42:09
01/03/16 20:42:38
01/03/16 20:43:38
01/03/16 20:44:08
01/03/16 20:46:27
01/03/16 20:46:57
01/03/16 20:51:04
01/03/16 20:51:24
01/03/16 20:51:44
01/03/16 20:52:04
01/03/16 20:58:22
01/03/16 20:58:42
01/03/16 20:59:12
01/03/16 21:00:12
01/03/16 21:00:22
01/03/16 21:01:12
01/03/16 21:57:09
01/03/16 21:57:29
01/03/16 21:59:29
01/03/16 21:59:39
01/03/16 21:59:49
01/03/16 22:00:09
01/03/16 22:00:17
01/03/16 22:00:47
01/03/16 22:00:57
01/03/16 22:04:07
01/03/16 22:04:26
01/03/16 22:08:04
01/03/16 22:07:25
01/03/16 22:08:05
01/03/16 22:08:14
01/03/16 22:08:44
01/03/16 22:09:04
01/03/16 22:09:54
01/03/16 22:10:24
01/03/16 22:10:34
```

End Date::

```
01/03/16 07:07:18
01/03/16 07:07:37
01/03/16 07:07:37
01/03/16 07:07:38
01/03/16 07:09:56
01/03/16 07:10:06
01/03/16 08:46:09
01/03/16 08:46:29
01/03/16 08:46:59
01/03/16 08:49:27
01/03/16 08:51:27
01/03/16 09:00:14
01/03/16 09:01:43
01/03/16 09:33:50
01/03/16 09:34:30
01/03/16 09:47:25
01/03/16 10:14:55
01/03/16 10:15:05
01/03/16 10:15:05
01/03/16 10:15:25
01/03/16 10:16:05
01/03/16 10:19:43
01/03/16 10:19:43
01/03/16 10:20:52
01/03/16 10:21:32
01/03/16 11:03:25
01/03/16 11:03:26
01/03/16 12:49:27
01/03/16 12:51:07
01/03/16 12:51:57
01/03/16 12:52:17
01/03/16 13:59:30
01/03/16 13:59:30
01/03/16 14:00:50
01/03/16 14:00:59
01/03/16 14:01:00
01/03/16 14:01:19
01/03/16 14:08:16
01/03/16 14:09:56
01/03/16 14:40:54
01/03/16 14:40:54
01/03/16 14:42:07
01/03/16 14:42:37
01/03/16 15:26:00
01/03/16 15:26:10
01/03/16 15:27:09
01/03/16 15:27:39
01/03/16 15:29:59
01/03/16 18:34:29
01/03/16 18:34:39
01/03/16 18:39:07
01/03/16 18:39:17
01/03/16 18:57:11
01/03/16 18:58:10
01/03/16 19:57:56
01/03/16 19:57:56
01/03/16 19:59:06
01/03/16 19:59:16
01/03/16 20:01:24
01/03/16 20:40:20
01/03/16 20:41:09
01/03/16 20:41:49
01/03/16 20:42:09
01/03/16 20:42:09
01/03/16 20:42:48
01/03/16 20:43:38
01/03/16 20:46:27
01/03/16 20:46:57
01/03/16 20:51:04
01/03/16 20:51:24
01/03/16 20:51:44
01/03/16 20:51:55
01/03/16 20:58:14
01/03/16 20:58:34
01/03/16 20:59:12
01/03/16 21:00:12
01/03/16 21:00:22
01/03/16 21:00:32
01/03/16 21:57:09
01/03/16 21:57:19
01/03/16 21:59:19
01/03/16 21:59:29
01/03/16 21:59:49
01/03/16 22:00:07
01/03/16 22:00:17
01/03/16 22:00:37
01/03/16 22:00:57
01/03/16 22:03:57
01/03/16 22:04:26
01/03/16 22:07:15
01/03/16 22:08:04
01/03/16 22:08:04
01/03/16 22:08:14
01/03/16 22:08:34
01/03/16 22:08:54
01/03/16 22:09:54
01/03/16 22:10:04
01/03/16 22:10:34
01/03/16 22:11:04
```

Location::

```
Bedroom
Living Room
Bathroom
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Bedroom
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Bedroom
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Kitchen
Living Room
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Door
Door
Living Room
Bathroom
Kitchen
Bedroom
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Bedroom
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Bedroom
Living Room
Bedroom
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Bedroom
Living Room
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Bathroom
Bedroom
Bathroom
Bedroom
Kitchen
Bedroom
Kitchen
Bathroom
Bedroom
Bedroom
Bathroom
Kitchen
Living Room
Kitchen
Bedroom
Living Room
```

How to merge these two data sets by time so that in the first data set such that for every range of start and end time in second data set it will show that location for the same time range in first data set.

E.g. for first row in 2nd data set the location is Bedroom from 29/02/16 21:58:03 to    01/03/16 07:07:18 so after joining it should show bedroom from first row till the end time i.e. 01/03/16 07:07:18 in 1st data set.

Comment: If it's 01/03/16 00:00:51 in the living room, isn't it the same date and time in the bathroom (unless your house straddles two timezones)?  There seems to be some missing links to the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste the same question here and at Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066282/how-to-merge-two-tables-as-mentioned-in-the-following-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start the End Date Column with 29/09/16 21:58:03 and Location Bedroom and continue with the normal Data you have to create the Table or array for the Vlookup formula. Then write your Date in another place like your first set.
Use the following Formula:
`=VLOOKUP(E3,$B$2:$C$101,2)`
Where E3 is the reference of the first date in set 1 (01-03-2016  12:00:01)
$B$2:$C$101 is the array End Date and Location (29-02-2016  9:58:03 Bedroom...)
2 is the column of Location
 your Data will look like the following picture, you can always copy paste special to another new sheet

[image]